# How to properly use createOrUpdateInRealm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence, realm

I am using Realm to handle persisting data to disk in my app. I am storing an ArticleCollection object to Realm (this just contains an array of NewsArticle objects).

I am using `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue` to either create a new ArticleCollection or update the existing one (achieved using a primary key on ArticleCollection).

This currently works well when the app fetches new articles it will overwrite the current collection of articles and replace with a new instance of ArticleCollection.

The issue is that whilst ArticleCollection is replaced (in Realm brwoser I can see the count of ArticleCollection is always 1 as expected), the number of NewsArticles always increases. It seems that sub objects of ArticleCollection (NewsArticle) never get replaced/deleted, only appended to.

How can I ensure that when I use `createOrUpdateInRealm`, it will delete all sub objects?

Comment: Can you confirm if `NewsArticles` has a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that are also using a primary key on your `NewsArticle` object. Otherwise those news articles won't be updated. That's why you are seeing an increasing number of news articles.